# search for next closest element not in a list

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to replace 2 alphabets (repeats ) from vector of 26 alphabets.

I already have 13 of 26 alphabets in my table (keys), so replacement alphabets should not be among those 13 'keys'.

I am trying to write code to replace `C & S` by next present alphabet which should not be part of 'keys'.

The following code is replacing repeat `C by D` and `S by T`, but those both letters are in my 'keys'. Could someone know how I can implement condition so that code will re-run loop if letter to be replace is already present in 'key'?

```
# alphabets <- toupper(letters)
keys <- c("I", "C", "P", "X", "H", "J", "S", "E", "T", "D", "A", "R", "L")
repeats <- c("C", "S")
index_of_repeat_in_26 <- which(repeats %in% alphabets)
# index_of_repeat_in_26 is 3 , 19
# available_keys <- setdiff(alphabets,keys)
available <- alphabets[available_keys]
# available <-  c("B", "F", "G", "K", "O", "Q", "U", "V", "W", "Y", "Z")
index_available_keys <- which(alphabets %in% available_keys)
# 2  6  7 11 15 17 21 22 23 25 26

for (i in 1:length(repeat)){
    for(j in 1:(26-sort(index_of_repeat_in_26)[1])){
        if(index_of_repeat_in_26[i]+j %in% index_available_keys){
            char_to_replace_in_key[i] <- alphabets[index_of_capital_repeat_in_26[i]+1]
        }
        else{
            cat("\n keys not available to replace \n")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the `while` function.

Comment: urelated, `LETTERS` produces the same output as `toupper(letters)`.

Comment: I tried while loop but program is still running     while (char_to_replace_in_key != (available)) {
  for (i in 1:length(repeat)){
    for(j in 1:(26-sort(index_of_repeat_in_26)[1]))){
      char_to_replace_in_key[t] <- alphabets[index_of_repeat_in_26 [t]+1]
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

```
keys <- c("I", "C", "P", "X", "H", "J", "S", "E", "T", "D", "A", "R", "L")
repeats <- c("C", "S")

y = sort(setdiff(LETTERS, keys))       # get the letters not present in 'keys' 
y = factor(y, levels = LETTERS)        # make them factor so that we can do numeric comparisons with the levels
y1 = as.numeric(y)                     # keep them numeric to compare
z  = factor(repeats, levels = LETTERS)
z1 = as.numeric(z)

func <- function(x) {         # so here, in each iteration, the index(in this case 1:4 gets passed)
           xx = y1 - z1[x]    # taking the difference between each 'repeat' element from all 'non-keys'
           xx = which(xx>0)[1]# choose the one with smallest difference(because 'y1'  is already sorted. So the first nearest non-key gets selected
           r = y[xx]          # extract the corresponding 'non-key' element            
           y <<- y[-xx]       # after i get the closest letter, I remove that from global list so that it doesn't get captured the next time
           y1 <<- y1[-xx]     # similarily removed from the equivalent numeric list
           r                  # return the extracted 'closest non-key' chracter 
 }

 # sapply is also a for-loop by itself, in which a single element get passed ro func at a time. 
 # Here 'seq_along' is used to pass the index. i.e. for 'C' - 1, for 'S' - 2 , etc gets passed.

 ans = sapply(seq_along(repeats), func)

if (any(is.na(ans))){
  cat("\n",paste0("keys not available to replace for ",
           paste0(repeats[which(is.na(ans))], collapse = ",")) ,
      "\n")
  ans <- ans[!is.na(ans)]
}
```

---

```
# example 2 with :
repeats <- c("Y", "Z")
# output : 
# keys not available to replace for Z 
# ans
# [1] Z
```

Note : to understand how each ieration of `sapply()` works : you should run `debug(func)` and then run the `sapply()` call. You can then check on console how each variable `xx`, `r` is getting evaluated. Hope this helps!

Comment: Joel, Thanks, very useful. Yes for this query it work splendidly.

Comment: when I have 25 keys (A-Y), 4 repeats (C,S,M,N) and have only one alphabet to replace(Z). The above code is replacing all repeats by Z. What I wanted was it should have replace only C by Z and for remaining S,M,N it should have display 'key not available' message. Do you have any idea how one can implement this condition through for loop with if statement? Or something similar?

Comment: @mr_swap ohhh! i didn't know of this condition. well that should be done! Right ow i don't have access to RStudio. Shall update you later

Comment: the problem still exists. Now I gave 24 keys (A-X), 4 repeats (CSMN). And it still replaces only C by Y, keeping others as it is.

Comment: It works :-), could you explain me how function executes this action line by line?

Comment: @mr_swap mind ticking this as an answr if this answered accurately!